# Output of basic Java not printing. Can't figure out why

Tags: java

I'm a freshman at uni and we have to make an assignment where we have to find the second smallest number in a line of integers. Now I THINK I got it but I can't get the result to print. Can anyone figure out why this is?

```
package SecondSmallest;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintStream;


public class SecondSmallest {

    public static void secondSmallestLoop() {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out);

        out.printf("Please enter a series of at least 2 integers: ");

        int smallest = in.nextInt();
        int secondSmallest = in.nextInt();

        while (in.hasNextInt()) {

            int next = in.nextInt();

            if (next < smallest) {
                secondSmallest = smallest;
                smallest = next;
            }

            else if (next < secondSmallest) {
                secondSmallest = next;
            }

        }

        out.print("The second smallest number is: " + secondSmallest);              
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SecondSmallest.secondSmallestLoop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use just `System.out.print("The second smallest number is: " + secondSmallest);`?

Comment: This works perfectly for me.

Comment: Or like `PrintStream out = System.out;` then `out.print("this");` if you want a shortcut to print. There is no point in wrapping a perfectly good `PrintStream` in another `new PrintStream()`.

Comment: Can you give a sample input and output, this isn't clear to me

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is better to have a condition to stop your scanner. So I would suggest to use a do-while instead. You also should use System.out.println, because it's ready to print in your console. You don't have to instantiate a PrintStream everytime. And by the way, your code is working, but it would be interesting to consider the thoughts we gave to you.

Comment: Thank you! I will review my code again with all of your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not defined stop point for the while loop.

`in.hasNextInt()` mean: If you input an integer, it will be continue. To stop it, you can input a character that isn't an integer.

Hope to helpful

Comment: Thanks for your advice it helped a lot!